# kvm use entire disk device

Tags: kvm

Is it possible when creating a virtual machine with virt-install to specify the `--disk` flag with something like `/dev/sdc` (assuming a hard drive on my host is at that location) instead of mapping it to a `.img` file? currently my command looks like:

```
sudo virt-install --name ubuntu-test \
 --ram 512 --vcpus 1 \
 --disk path=/home/username/test.img,size=10 \
 --location http://mirror.facebook.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-  amd64 \
 --graphics none
```

can i change it to something like?:

```
sudo virt-install --name ubuntu-test7 \
 --ram 512 --vcpus 1 \
 --disk path=/dev/sdc \
 --location http://mirror.facebook.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-  amd64 \
 --graphics none
```

Comment: What happened when you tried? A quick glance at the manual page for `virt-install` indicates that a file or block device are both fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works just fine.

In my case I use LVM created devices and I was able to install Kali Linux in a VM with

```
virt-install -n kali -r 2048 --disk path=/dev/Raid10/vm.kali -c /torrents/kali-linux-2016.1-amd64.iso -w bridge:br0 --vnc --vnclisten=0.0.0.0 --os-type=linux --os-variant=debianwheezy
```

In this case the resulting XML file built was

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
  <source dev='/dev/Raid10/vm.kali'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

We can see this uses the `virtio` driver.

The `/dev/Raid10/vm.kali` would be the equivalent of your `/dev/sdc`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am having trouble wrapping my head around virtio and how this all plays into it as well? http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Virtio - It is unclear to me how, within the guest VM, that /dev/vda is created as /dev/vda seems to be the KVM standard.

Comment: See updated answer; virtio was used on this.

Comment: I see, so this line <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/> sets it to /dev/vda within the guest?

Comment: Yup.  If you'd have pointed it to a file then that segment would have said `    <disk type='file' device='disk'>` but the target would still be `vda` and `libvirt`.

Comment: awesome, thanks. I am using LVM as well but I think i need to modify my preseed / partitioning because right now `df -h` outputs:

    `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--host--vg-root  8.8G  897M  7.5G  11% /`
    `/dev/sda1                          472M   53M  396M  12% /boot`

Comment: `vgs` should tell you if you have any free space in your volume group.  If you're only assigning 9G to `/` then I expect you have plenty of free space to `lvcreate` new LVs for new VMs to run in; that's exactly what I do :-)

Comment: I guess I am getting hung up on why it is assigning /dev/sda1 to /boot ... that must be the default used in my preseed file because it is pretty stock example pressed

Comment: Isn't that your physical host?  Or are you using LVM _inside_ your VMs?  On physical hosts, `/boot` is typically a small partition outside of any LV so that `grub` or `grub2` can be loaded from the BIOS/UEFI/whatever.

Comment: ah yes, sorry I am using LVM inside my VMs, i need to play around with it more.. doesn't seem like the best approach

Comment: Anyway, getting back to your original question, you can point `--disk` to a file or to a volume or to a partition or to a whole disk and it'll work the same way; the virtio question is really a separate issue.